# Authelia (Docker-Compose) can't find/read existing configuration files (Volumes)

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, docker-compose, docker-volume

I tried to install Authelia as oAuth Server with Docker-Compose. But everytime when I start the container, the logs are saying this

```
time="2020-05-23T16:51:09+02:00" level=error msg="Provide a JWT secret using \"jwt_secret\" key"
time="2020-05-23T16:51:09+02:00" level=error msg="Please provide `ldap` or `file` object in `authentication_backend`"
time="2020-05-23T16:51:09+02:00" level=error msg="Set domain of the session object"
time="2020-05-23T16:51:09+02:00" level=error msg="A storage configuration must be provided. It could be 'local', 'mysql' or 'postgres'"
time="2020-05-23T16:51:09+02:00" level=error msg="A notifier configuration must be provided"
panic: Some errors have been reported

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.startServer()
    github.com/authelia/authelia/cmd/authelia/main.go:41 +0xc80
main.main.func1(0xc00009c000, 0xc0001e6100, 0x0, 0x2)
    github.com/authelia/authelia/cmd/authelia/main.go:126 +0x20
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0xc00009c000, 0xc000020190, 0x2, 0x2, 0xc00009c000, 0xc000020190)
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.7/command.go:842 +0x29d
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0xc00009c000, 0xc0007cdf58, 0x4, 0x4)
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.7/command.go:943 +0x317
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(...)
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v0.0.7/command.go:883
main.main()
    github.com/authelia/authelia/cmd/authelia/main.go:143 +0x166
```

and the container is restarting.
I don't realy understand why and where this behavior comes from. I've used named volumes just like binded volumes but it is still the same error. Maybe someone can tell me where I'm doing a (probably stupid) mistake, becuase I don't see it.

My compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  authelia:
    image: "authelia/authelia:latest"
    container_name: authelia
    restart: "unless-stopped"
#    security_opt:
#      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - "web"
      - "intern"
    volumes:
      - ./authelia:/var/lib/authelia
      - ./configuration.yml:/etc/authelia/configuration.yml:ro
      - ./users_database.yml:/etc/authelia/users_database.yml
# Had to bind this volumen, without it, docker creates an own volumen with empty configuration.yml and 
# users_database.yml
      - ./data:/etc/authelia  

    environment:
      - TZ=$TZ
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.rule=Host(`secure.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.tls.certresolver=le"
      # Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.middlewares=chain-no-auth@file"
      # HTTP Service
      - "traefik.http.routers.authelia-rtr.service=authelia-svc"
      - "traefik.http.services.auhtelia-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9091"


networks:
  web:
    external: true
  intern:
    external: true
```

The files and folders under the volumes section are existing and configuration.yml is not empty. I use an admin (non-root) user with sudo permissions. 
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong and why authelia isn't able to find or read the configuration.yml?

Comment: Seems like noone has any idea :/

Answer (score 0):

Verify your `configuration.yml` file. These errors show up when your yml syntax is incorrect. In particular:

- double-check indentation,
- put your domain names in quotation marks (this was my problem when I encountered that).

See also discussion [here](https://github.com/authelia/authelia/issues/1053).